# Sorting NSMutableDictionary with sortOrder

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, nsmutabledictionary

For a sectioned tableView I need to sort my books by category.sortOrder

```
    NSMutableDictionary *theDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (Book *object in self.books) {            
        NSMutableArray *theMutableArray = [theDictionary objectForKey:object.category.categoryName];
        if ( theMutableArray == nil ) {
            theMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
            [theDictionary setObject:theMutableArray forKey:object.category.categoryName];
        }
        [theMutableArray addObject:object];
    }
    self.sections = [[theDictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

How can I include the category.sortOrder value in my Dictionary, so I can sort my sections correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, you should create a class to hold the values for each section, then add those to your dictionary. You can do this all in your controller if you don't want the extra file, but you could also create another file if you wanted:

```
@interface TableSection
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *order;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *objects;
@end

@implementation TableSection
@synthesize name;
@synthesize order;
@synthesize objects;
@end


NSMutableDictionary *sections = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (Book *object in self.books) {
    TableSection *section = [categories objectForKey:object.category.categoryName];
    if ( section == nil ) {
        section = [[TableSection alloc] init];
        section.name = object.category.categoryName;
        section.order = object.category.sortOrder;
        section.objects = [NSMutableArray array];
        [sections setObject:section forKey:object.category.categoryName];

    }
    [(NSMutableArray *)section.objects addObject:object];
}
self.sections = [[categories allValues] sortUsingDescriptors:
                 [NSArray arrayWithObject:
                  [NSSortDescriptor descriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES]]];
```

Comment: I think I have theDictionary setup wrong, because I can only check allKeys and not allObjects?

Comment: Won't work like that. I guess I need so first insert the sortOrder into my dictionary. Now I just have the category.categoryName

Comment: For what purpose? Is sort order not the order of your objects in their categories?

Comment: The books should then appear in alphabetical order of the title in the sorted categories.

Comment: Updated for that (sorry I misunderstood the original question). You'll still have to loop back through and sort the objects in the sections, but this should cover the sections.